# Highlight selected item with backbone router callbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, coffeescript, backbone-events

### The Application Layout

I have an application, with a **sidebar** that holds many items and a **main** div which displays these items. There is also a simple `Backbone.Router`, a `ItemsCollection` and a `Item` model. I've got a `SidebarView` for the sidebar and a `ShowView` to show the selected item.

```
                  +-------------------------+
                  | http://app.de/#/show/3  |   <-- Current URL
                  +-------------------------+
                  | Sidebar | Main          |
                  |---------+---------------|
                  | Item 1  |               |
 SidebarView -->  |---------|    Display    |
                  | Item 2  |    Item  3    | <-- MainView handled by
                  |---------|    here       |          MainRouter
Selected Item --> | Item 3 *|               |
                  +---------+---------------+
```

On startup, I initialize the `SidebarView` and the `MainRouter`. The `SidebarView` attaches its `render` method to the `ItemCollection#all` event. I also attach the `ItemCollection#refresh` event to `Backbone.history.start()`, then I fetch the `ItemCollection`.

```
$(function() {
  window.router = new App.MainRouter;
  window.sidebar = new App.SidebarView;
  ItemCollection.bind("reset", _.once(function(){Backbone.history.start()}));
  ItemCollection.fetch();
});
```

### The problem

I want to highlight the currently selected item. This works by binding the `route.show` event from the router:

```
# I removed all code which is not necessary to understand the binding
class SidebarView extends Backbone.View
  el: ".sidebar"

  initialize: () ->
    window.router.bind 'route:show', @highlight_item

  # The route is routed to #/show/:id, so I get the id here
  highlight_item: (id) ->
    $(".sidebar .collection .item").removeClass("selected")
    $("#item-" + id).addClass("selected")
```

It works perfectly when I select an Item when the app is loaded. But when the page is loaded with `#/show/123` as the URL, the item is not highlighted. I run the debugger and found out, that the sidebar is not rendered yet, when the `highlight_item` callback is invoked.

### Possible solutions

Is there any way to reorder the bindings, so that the `Item#refresh` event invokes `SidebarView#render` first and then start the routing?

Maybe a workaround that just takes the current route from the `window.router` (I did not find any method in the Backbone Docs) and highlights the Item when its rendered?

Or is my initialization just stupid and should I handle things differently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do two things:

1. `highlight_item` could keep track of which item is supposed to be highlighted.
2. Update your `render` to initialize the highlighted item.

Something like this:

```
initialize: () ->
  @highlighted_id = null
  window.router.bind 'route:show', @highlight_item

render: () ->
  # Set everything up inside @el as usual
  @highlight_current()
  @

highlight_item: (id) =>
  @highlighted_id = id
  @highlight_current()

highlight_current: () ->
  return unless(@highlighted_id)
  $(@el)
    .find('.selected').removeClass('selected')
    .end()
    .find("#item-#{@highlighted_id}").addClass('selected')
```

So, as long as `highlight_item` gets called, `highlight_current` will also get called with the appropriate `@highlighted_id` set and everything should work out.

Comment: Great! This also gets me around fiddling with `window.location` to extract the `id` and makes everything DRY. Thank you! :)